# Why can't you change the value of an element of an array using for-each loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, increment

[image]

I know the answer is that none of them work, but why exactly can't you change the value of an element of an array using for-each loop? Also for the code segment at top, to update each value, why wouldn't you need to reassign it to numbers[j]?

Comment: The first example (`numbers[j]++;`) uses an "increment" operator, which increases the variable by 1, and is functionally the same as `numbers[j] = numbers[j] + 1;`

Comment: and I haven't used Java in a while, but I would think something similar to this would work: `for (int num : numbers) { int index = findIndexOf(num, numbers); numbers[index]++; }` but that's just extra work to find the index of the value you want to update instead of using a for loop which does that same thing. I believe `num++` would only increase the value within the loop, but doesn't change the original variable, `num[j]++` - `j` is undefined here, so that would throw an exception, and `numbers[num]++` doesn't work because `num` isn't the index, it's the value itself.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Complete waste of your time and our bandwidth. Post the text.

Comment: 'numbers' is an array of (primitive) int values.  'num' is a (primitive) int value.   It is not possible in Java that 'num' is somehow an alias for an entry in an array.  It is a copy of the value, and thus anything you do to 'num' cannot affect the array.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you **can** - but you need the thing you are using `for-each` loop to contain the range of valid array indices. For example, with an `IntStream` in Java 8+ like

```
IntStream.range(0, numbers.length).forEach(j -> numbers[j]++);
```

The reason you can't do that with a `for (int x : numbers)` is because the `for-each` loop ***hides*** the `Iterator` or iteration mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

In the body of a for-each loop, you're getting a local copy of each element in the array (or any other object that implements [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/Iterable.html) for that matter). Any operation you do to the loop variable are done to the local copy, and not the array element itself. So this for-each loop:

```java
for (int num : numbers) {
  num++;
}
```

is more or less compiled as:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  int num = numbers[i];
  num++;
}
```

Since primitive types (like `int`) are value types (they contain a value, not a reference to another value), copying it creates an independent value copy. If a reference type is used instead, the value copied is the reference itself, so any changes you make to the loop variable are reflected on the referenced object. That's why this works:

```java
class IntHandle {
  int value;
  IntHandle(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}

var numbers = new IntHandle[] {new IntHandle(1)};
for (var num : numbers) {
  num.value++; // Equivalent to numbers[i].value++
}
```